# How to configure Wildfily 12 or JBoss with MySQL Connector /J 8?

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, jdbc, wildfly

I got this to finally connect after reading old documentation.  I am not sure if this is the best way, so if you have suggestions for better connection strings or wildfly pool settings please post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Enter in the file path `${EAP_HOME}/modules/system/layers/base` and create the directories `com/mysql/driver8/main`.

Into the folder main copy the driver(mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar) library jar, and create a file module.xml as showed in the sample below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.mysql.driver8">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

Then go to /wildfly-12.0.0.Final/standalone/standalone.xml copy and paste this into

```
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/MySqlDS8" pool-name="MySqlDS8">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?useSSL=false&amp;useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&amp;useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC</connection-url>
                <driver>mysql8</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>root</user-name>
                    <password>12341234</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
                </validation>
            </datasource>
```

Then go to the  section and copy and paste this.

```
   <driver name="mysql8" module="com.mysql.driver8">
       <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
   </driver>
```

Comment: Is **driver8** needed in the path com/mysql/driver8/main? I could only get it to work with com/mysql/main path

Comment: Please note that I haven't worked on this since 2018. But from what I remember, I will attempt to answer your question. It is not unheard of to have multiple mysql drivers installed because there maybe multiple apps running in the same instance of JBOSS/Wildfly. So, the name "driver8" was the identifier for which mysql driver I was setting up. At the time mysql driver 5 was more popular, so both were installed.

Comment: From what I remember, name="com.mysql.driver8" in the module sets the path. In the drivers, you identify drivers to be installed in the instance.